# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error, php-8

I got the error from the title after I update to PHP 8. The code is similar to the below and it said the error is on the line:
if(is_array($course_data['steps']['h']["sfwd-lessons"])){

full code here:

```
// bail out if this is not an event item
    if ('sfwd-courses' !== get_post_type($post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    $course_data  = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ld_course_steps', true);
    if (!empty($course_data)) {
        $lessons = array_keys($course_data['steps']['h']["sfwd-lessons"]);
        $quizes = array_keys($course_data['steps']['h']["sfwd-quiz"]);
    }

$lesson_data = [];
    // Extract all steps of the courses
    if(is_array($course_data['steps']['h']["sfwd-lessons"])){
        foreach($course_data['steps']['h']["sfwd-lessons"] as $lesson){
            $lesson_data = array_merge($lesson_data,array_values(array_keys($lesson["sfwd-topic"])));
            $lesson_data = array_merge($lesson_data,array_values(array_keys($lesson["sfwd-quiz"])));
            foreach($lesson["sfwd-topic"] as $topic){
                $lesson_data = array_merge($lesson_data,array_values(array_keys($topic["sfwd-quiz"])));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in PHP 8, this code error used to throw a 'warning' but now it's a fatal error. Don't worry, it's probably a pretty easy fix!

The issue is that $course_data from your sample code is being returned as a string, and you're trying to use array offsets to on it. Try `var_dump($course_data)` right after the line that defines $course_data and see what type of data it's returning.

Note that the third argument in `get_post_meta()` being set to true makes it return a 'single value', vs an array, so that's likely the issue. It's tough to say exactly what the fix is here without seeing what your data looks like, but the first step is definitely examining what `get_post_meta()` is returning for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Before the error was for the line started with @lessons and the fix was to add the line of code that is under  $coursedata=get_post_meta   etc etc.
When I var dump the code it shows me string(0) when the third parameter is set to true and array(0) { } when the third parameter has the default value of false.

Comment: Gotcha, so it seems like for whatever reason that post you're checking doesn't have the 'ld_course_steps' meta set, as that array is returning as empty. However, it seems like you're on the right track now with the illegal string offset error!

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help
i was able to fix the errors.